# Extend the HTML Grid for adding div at the end of Html Grid (MVC Contrib)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcgrid, htmlextensions

I have search the web to find a syntax or a guide to this but with no success.

I will appreciate any help.

I have implemented a Grid in a view, and instead of using the paging of the grid view i am trying to implement a button "View More" at the end of the grid that load more data to the grid view.

See the code

```
@Html.Grid(Model.Orders).Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.For(c => @Html.AddInstitudeRetangle(c.User.Institute.InstitudeColor, c.User.Institute.InstituteName)).Named("");
            columns.For(c => @Html.CheckBox(c.OrderID.ToString(), false, new { @ID = "cb-" + c.OrderID.ToString(), @Name = "cb-" + c.OrderID.ToString() })).Header("<th><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"chkHeader\" /></th>");
            columns.For(c => @Ajax.LinkForBootstrapModalNo("OrderDetails", "OrdersManagement", c.OrderID.ToString(), new { OrderID = c.OrderID }, new { id = "OrderID" }).LoadingPanel("Please Wait Loading...").ToMVCHtmlString()).Named(OrdersManagementStrings.OrderID);
            columns.For(c => @Html.GetOrderTypeIcon(c.OrderTypeStatus, c.OrderTypeStatus.GetDescription())).Named(OrdersManagementStrings.OrderType);
            columns.For(c => String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm}", c.CreationDate)).Named(OrdersManagementStrings.OrderDate);
            columns.For(c => String.Format("{0} {1}", c.User.FirstName, c.User.LastName)).Named(OrdersManagementStrings.CustomerName);
            columns.For(c => c.User.Institute.InstituteName).Named(OrdersManagementStrings.AffiliateName);
            columns.For(c => c.TotalCost).Named(OrdersManagementStrings.TotalCost);
            columns.For(c => c.ShippingTypeEnum.GetDescription()).Named(OrdersManagementStrings.ShippingType);
            columns.For(c => c.Address.FullAddress).Named(OrdersManagementStrings.Address);
            columns.For(c => c.OrderStatusEnum.GetDescription()).Named(OrdersManagementStrings.OrderStatus);
        }).Attributes(@class => "table table-hover table-responsive table-condensed", @id => "ordersTable")

        <div id="scroll" data-itemsperpage="50" data-spy="scroll">Load More</div
```

Now when a user clicks on the div at the end i am using ajax request to load more data.

Now, i want to create an **extension** the will add this div to the end of the Grid.

So at the end the syntax will be something as

```
columns.For(c => c.OrderStatusEnum.GetDescription())
.Named(OrdersManagementStrings.OrderStatus);
            })
.Attributes(@class => "table table-hover table-responsive table-condensed", @id => "ordersTable")
.LoadMoreButton(50);
```

The number 50 represent the number of rows per page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the source, I think it might be easier to extend `HtmlTableGridRenderer` as a `ScrollingHtmlTableGridRenderer` and use

```
@Html.Grid(Model.Orders)
     .RenderUsing(new ScrollingHtmlTableGridRenderer(50))
     ...
```

then in `ScrollingHtmlTableGridRenderer` override `RenderGridEnd` to add the extra DIV

```
public class ScrollingHtmlTableGridRenderer<T> : HtmlTableGridRenderer<T>
    where T : class
{
     private readonly int _itemsPerPage;

     public ScrollingHtmlTableGridRenderer(int itemsPerPage)
     {
          _itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
     }

     protected override void RenderGridEnd()
     {
          base.RenderGridEnd();
          RenderText("<div id=\"scroll\" data-itemsperpage=\"" + _itemsPerPage + \"" data-spy=\"scroll\">Load More</div>");
     }
}
```

You might be able to do this as an extension that basically creates a new renderer and propagates all the data from the underlying grid model to it, but the `Grid` class seems to be built to be extended by replacing the renderer with one that handles your custom needs rather than by extensions on `IGridOptionsModel`.

Comment: Hi, this works! thank you. Can you please guide me to a post or key works where i can read and learn more on this? In particular ScrollingHtmlTableGridRenderer<T> : HtmlTableGridRenderer<T>
    where T : class

Comment: @silagy - the source is available at https://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest